# How I can make this code work faster? I have a time limit of 6.5 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, hashmap, hashtable

I need this code to work faster. I'm assuming that the problem could be solved by creating correct `key:value` pairs in "filedics". I guess that it should look something like this:

```
word: [{ id: 1, count: 1}, { id: 2, count: 1}];
```

My code is working good in terms of logic, but when it receiving a lot of strings as an input it can`t handled it.

But maybe there are some other mistakes that I don`t see.

```
const _reader = _readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
});

const _inputLines = [];
let _curLine = 0;

_reader.on("line", (line) => {
  _inputLines.push(line);
});

process.stdin.on("end", solve);

function result(reqs, files, n, m) {
  const filedics = files.map(() => ({}));

  for (let fi = 0; fi < files.length; ++fi) {
    const file = files[fi];
    const fdic = filedics[fi];
    const usedwords = {};

    for (let wf = 0; wf < file.length; ++wf) {
      const rword = file[wf];
      if (usedwords[rword]) continue;
      usedwords[rword] = true;
      if (fdic[rword] == null) fdic[rword] = numofword(rword, file);
    }
  }

  let rel = 0;
  const relfiles = [];

  for (let ri = 0; ri < reqs.length; ++ri) {
    for (let fi = 0; fi < filedics.length; ++fi) {
      const fdic = filedics[fi];
     
      for (let wi = 0; wi < reqs[ri].length; ++wi) {
        const wordReq = reqs[ri][wi];
         const usedwords = {};
        if (usedwords[wordReq]) continue;
        usedwords[wordReq] = true;
        if (fdic[wordReq]) {
          rel += fdic[wordReq];
        }
      }
      if (rel) relfiles.push([rel, fi + 1]);
      rel = 0;
    }
    const sr = relfiles.sort(([rel1], [rel2]) => rel2 - rel1);

    for (let i = 0; i < 5 && i < sr.length; ++i)
      process.stdout.write(sr[i][1] + " ");
    process.stdout.write("\n");
    relfiles.length = 0;
  }
}

function numofword(word, file) {
  let n = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < file.length; ++i) {
    if (word === file[i]) n++;
  }
  return n;
}

function solve() {
  const n = readInt();
  const files = arrLines(n);
  const m = readInt();
  const reqs = arrLines(m);
  let res = result(reqs, files, n, m);
}
```

I have for example 2 arrays with 3 subarrays in each.

```
INPUT
3
[
  [ 'i', 'love', 'coffee' ],
  [ 'coffee', 'with', 'milk', 'and', 'sugar' ],
  [ 'free', 'tea', 'for', 'everyone' ]
]

3 
[
  [ 'i', 'like', 'black', 'coffee', 'without', 'milk' ],
  [ 'everyone', 'loves', 'new', 'year' ],
  [ 'mary', 'likes', 'black', 'coffee', 'without', 'milk' ]
]
```

Goal is to output subarrays by number that have most matches, in descending order. For example the output for this code should be

```
1 2
3
2 1
```

Comment: You said you're supposed to output strings, but you output numbers. What do those numbers represent?

Comment: If the code works this maybe a better fit for [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) (but review [their site criteria](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) first).

Comment: why not produce your random values with a simple `Math.random()` ?

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding what the output means. Are they supposed to be array indexes? Indexes start at 0, not 1.

Comment: What are the numbers before the arrays in the input? If they're the lengths of the arrays, why are they needed when you can just use `.length` to get an array's length?

Answer (score 0):

(1) I don't see the reason to maintain separate dictionaries for each file if always all entries are checked against all filedicts and the result is summed up. Instead one could just use one filedict for all files.

(2) `numofword` is extremely inefficient, as for every word in the file the whole file is scanned again, turning this into an O(n^2) algorithm. Simply traversing the file once and counting up turns that into O(n).

(3) Maps can be slightly better for lots of keys than objects.

(4) I'm not quite sure what `arrLines` does, but usually one can maximize the throughput by reading and processing data in chunks and processing multiple files in parallel.

```
const occurences = new Map();

for (const file of files) {
  for(const word of file) { 
    occurences.set(word, (occurences.get(word) ?? 0) + 1);
  }
}

for (const seq of seqs) {
  let score = 0;
  const checked = new Set();
  for (const word of seq) {
    if (checked.has(word)) continue;  
    checked.add(word);
    score +=occurences.get(word) ?? 0;
  }
  // collect seqs and sort
}
```